# iterate through selected cells in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-macros

I want to add a text to last column of all selected rows:

```
var sh = ss.getActiveSheet(); 
  lCol = sh.getLastColumn()
  var selected_cells=ss.getActiveRangeList()
  var rgs=selected_cells.getRanges();
  for (var i = 0; i < rgs.length; i++) {
    var range=rgs[i];
    var lRow=range.getRow();
    var cell = sh.getRange(lRow,lCol+1,1,1);
    var firstname=sh.getRange(lRow, 2).getValue();
    var lastname=sh.getRange(lRow, 3).getValue();
    var email=sh.getRange(lRow, 8).getValue();
    var link="http://192.168.80.1/d/?email="+email+"&firstname="+firstname+"&lastname="+lastname;
    cell.setFormula("=HYPERLINK(\""+link+"\",\"click\")");
  }
```

But it justs adds to first row.
What am I missing?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I could study from your question. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to put `=HYPERLINK()` to the last column of the selected rows. If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? I was interested in your question. So I thought of about your issue, because I thought that I would like to study from your question.

#### Modification points :

- For example, when you select the cells of "A1", "B2" and "C3", the range list has 3 elements in an array. Those are "A1", "B2" and "C3". When you select the cells of "A1", "A2" and "A3", the range list has 1 element in an array. Those are "A1:A3".

  - From your script, I thought that this may be the main cause for your issue. So I would like to propose the following flow and the modified script.

#### Flow :

1. At first, parse the retrieved range list.

   - By this, the list is separated by the continuous cells and the individual cell.
2. Using the parsed list, import the values you want.

When you use this modified script, please run `main()`.

#### Modified script :

```
function getFormula(e) {
  var firstname = e[1];
  var lastname = e[2];
  var email = e[7];
  var link = "http://192.168.80.1/d/?email=" + email + "&firstname=" + firstname + "&lastname=" + lastname;
  return "=HYPERLINK(\"" + link + "\",\"click\")";
}

// Please run this function, when you use this modified script.
function main() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var lCol = sh.getLastColumn();
  var selected_cells = ss.getActiveRangeList();
  var rgs = selected_cells.getRanges();
  for (var i = 0; i < rgs.length; i++) {
    var numRows = rgs[i].getNumRows();
    if (numRows > 1) {
      var values = sh.getRange(rgs[i].getRow(), 1, numRows, lCol).getValues();
      var formulas = values.map(function(e) {return [getFormula(e)]});
      sh.getRange(rgs[i].getRow(), lCol + 1, numRows, 1).setFormulas(formulas);
    } else {
      var e = sh.getRange(rgs[i].getRow(), 1, 1, lCol).getValues()[0];
      sh.getRange(rgs[i].getRow(), lCol + 1, 1, 1).setFormula(getFormula(e));
    }
  }
}
```

#### Note :

- From your script, in the modified script, it supposes that `firstname`, `lastname` and `email` are in column B, column C and column H, respectively. If you want to change this, please modify it.

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.